# get current logged in user in Parse.com cloud code

Tags: express, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

How to get current user in Cloud Code at Parse.com ?
Currently I am trying to use this code in app.js:

```
app.get('/me', function(req, res) {
  var user = Parse.User.current();
  var name = user.get("displayName");

  //var aboutText = user.get("aboutText");
  res.render('personal', {displayName: name,
                          aboutText: "Hi, Quentin! Start making your ideas and projects real just now, but at first tell about yourself!"
                          });
});
```

But get "Internal Server Error".
How is it possible to get the user, which is currently logged in?
Seems that the reason for the error is this line:

```
  var name = user.get("displayName");
```

If I change parameter in "get" to username, it anyway gives me an error. I have displayName column in my database. What am I doing wrong?